# Eliminate white outline around text from image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr

I am trying to develop an OCR app for mobile.

So before passing it to OCR engine i am applying some filters and binarizing the image for better results.

I am using adaptive gaussian threshold which gives me pretty nice results but along with some dots and noise around the text (as you can observe in image below) which leads to error in OCR output.
[image: Binarized image]

Now this is just a small segment of larger image.
[image]

The reason i have understood is because  this  white outline around the text which can be observed only when i zoom the image significantly:

[image]

which i try to minimize by applying gaussian blurring before binarizing it. But still i believe i can get better results if i can understand and eliminate the cause of that white outline around the text.

I am also adding the [images](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2PTs7VIu4EfdV8tZEpXTXAxQk0)
I have explained the details of image in their name.

I am getting good results, but just trying to get some more insights and trying to explore if there is any other or better way of achieving the same.

Any guidance or direction would be of great help.
I hope i am clear with my question. Feel free to ask any details.

Thank you.

Comment: the white outline is there to enhance text visual appearence (for example if background is image) ... find the average background color (corners) and set all pixels brighter then that to this color that should remove the white and preserve characters unchanged

Comment: So is that mobile does internally to enhance the image readability? Well i am able to eliminate to huge extent using gaussian blur and then applying adaptive gaussian threshold with larger kernal size (15 to be precise) and i was able to obtain good results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [morphological](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwihgpLqoKbJAhUTjo4KHV8UDisQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcpsc.ualr.edu%2Fmilanova%2Fimage_processing%2Fweek5%2FMorphological%2520Image%2520Processing_part1.ppt&usg=AFQjCNHtN8zsEjKHhaJogDdB6N2tPfZG_w&bvm=bv.108194040,d.c2E)  operations?  This will decrease the white shade, provided you choose an optimum filter size and shape (circular disc operator).

It would be more useful if you can mention the sequence of operations you are performing on your image to see at what stage you are getting the white shade.

I think dilation will help here. MATLAB accepts gray image for dilation and does a wonderful job. Try it with OpenCV. I had done it earlier.

What type of binary thresholding technique are you using?

Comment: thank you for response. I have tried morphological operations. But doesnt seem to help much. I mean some letters do get enhanced  but for some it acts negatively. So not so positive result at the end. I have tried opening operation (imopen of MATLAB), though image is more clear but some numbers get mixed up and makes more harder for oCR to process it.

Comment: What type of binary thresholding technique are you using?. I had used an adaptive thresholding technique (to convert to binary). I had got it working.  You are right. It is difficult if the characters are joint. I think you still need to work on the filter size of those morphological operations and develop a simple threshold algorithm.  You could divide the image into several windows and have different threshold for each window.

Comment: I am using adaptive Gaussian thresholding of opencv.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are going to implement for mobile, what about just convert it to a binary image (just used Matlab to show).

```
img = imread('OGGjn.png');
imgb = im2bw(img);
imshow(imgb);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi, appreciate your reply. Coming to my point, this is just a enlarged sample from entire image. Its actually a pathology report, and this absesnt is just a part of it. This same method cannot be applied to whole page since the illumination level is different in different  section of page. So applying adaptive gaussian thresholding sometimes gives blobs and broken letters which at times become's a problem.

Comment: I just answer the given question. Kindly provide whole page and necessary requirements of yours for a general solution.

Comment: Most OCR works better and faster on black & white level, so binarization is a very typical preprocessing step.  In fact, I do it in all my apps and OCR applications.  Perhaps you can use a different "adaptive" binarization technique or even better a library that is especially designed for this task.

Comment: @IIya Evdokimov, actually i have applied "adaptive blurring" first to eliminate that noise caused by the white lining around the letters, and after that i apply "adaptive gaussian thresholding", you can check the same in link above(recently updated). And specific library...can you gimme some link or any direction. appreciate your help.